# Ember record does not show up after save

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I followed this https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/

But after create record and save, the record does not automatically show up. The page to list all the records uses `peekAll` so it didn't fire up to the server, but since the record created to the store, I think it should be seen by Ember locally.

From the developer toolbar, I can see the data has been created but it is `clean`, is this why? How can I make this new record shown? I worked with Ember before, this had never been a problem. I am using v2.8.0

[image]

Comment: Be specific about  "the record does not automatically show up.". How are you trying to display/access it?

Comment: Using standard way, route loading a model, each the model in template, then create a new record from store of that model within a controller and save it. I think the list of the model should reflect whatever in the store as long as it be successfully saved into the store.

Comment: I am getting close to the reason, but not sure. I am using component for the listing and another component to create the model. Before I used route. I guess component won't be notified about model change, but route maybe.

Comment: Maybe you can create an ember-twiddle to help us get to the bottom of this.  I'm not sure exactly what is going on. Are you retrieving all the records first with find? Before peeking them? Tell us more! : )

Comment: I didn't find it on this route because I find them in anther route already so I only peek them. But I think peeking is not the problem. I think the problem is that I have used a parent component holding the list of the records that I peeked. And I toggle another component to allow me to create a new record. After saved, I toggle it off. And the new record is not instantly displayed on the parent component. My solution now is to manually peek again after save. I think maybe this is the nature of component, not binding to the data store? I don't know how to put it.

Comment: show us route model hook?  Calling `toArray()` from `peekAll` will not update automatically when you update store.